# rspec test GET #index - expected collection contained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I test., that index action 'populates an array of all questions.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe QuestionsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    before do
      @questions = FactoryGirl.create_list(:question, 2)
      get :index
    end  

    it 'populates an array of all questions' do
      binding.pry
      expect(assigns(:questions)).to match_array(@questions)  
    end
    it 'renders index view' do
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)  
    end
  end
end
```

controllers/questions_controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @questions = Question.all        
    end
end
```

factories/questions.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    title "MyString"
    body "MyText"
  end
end
```

When running tests display error:

1) QuestionsController GET #index populates an array of all questions
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:questions)).to match_array(@questions)

```
   expected collection contained:  

[#<Question id: 37, title: "MyString", body: "MyText", created_at: "2016-10-31 19:37:12", updated_at:...: "MyString", body: "MyText", created_at: "2016-10-31 19:37:12", updated_at: "2016-10-31 19:37:12">]
       actual collection contained:    [#<Question id: 15, title: "MyString", body: "MyText", created_at: "2016-10-30 21:23:52", updated_at:...: "MyString", body: "MyText", created_at: "2016-10-31 19:37:12", updated_at: "2016-10-31 19:37:12">]
       the extra elements were:        [#<Question id: 15, title: "MyString", body: "MyText", created_at: "2016-10-30 21:23:52", updated_at:...: "MyString", body: "MyText", created_at: "2016-10-30 21:23:52", updated_at: "2016-10-30 21:23:52">]
 # ./spec/controllers/questions_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why not the same elements of the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you need to create questions in db? if you're testing that `@questions` is getting populated, you can stub those db calls, something like

```
describe 'GET #index' do
  before do
    @questions = [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:question)]
    allow(Question).to receive(:all).and_return(@questions)
    get :index
  end  

  it 'populates an array of all questions' do
    expect(assigns(:questions)).to match_array(@questions)  
  end
end
```

You don't need to create actual db records if you just want to test the assignment.

Comment: can you explain, what do this code:  @questions = [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:question)]
      allow(Question).to receive(:all).and_return(@questions)

Comment: sure, `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed` will create an ActiveRecord object (with all of its properties) without writing into the database. the `allow(...).to receive` call is used to mock (in this case) a call to the database, so, that's saying: ok, when `Question.all` gets call, return `@questions`... since you're not testing the model here, you can mock db calls, in fact, you don't need a controller test at all if you code an integration test that exercise the whole stack

Comment: @mr_sudaca your variant throws me the following error: `undefined method 'order' for #<Array:0x00562a87b61b08>`

Comment: yes, because the ActiveRecord call is stubbed. One way (midly ugly) is to stub `order` method in `@questions`, like: `allow(@questions).to receive(:order).and_return(@questions)`... but, if you want to test the outcome of `order` method (sorted questions) this will pass a false positive